# RuntimeError: DataLoader worker (pid 27351) is killed by signal: Killed

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm running the data loader below which applies a filter to a microscopy image prior to training. In order to count the red and green. This code filters the red cells. Since I have applied this to the code I keep on getting the error message above. I have tried increasing the memory allocation to the maximum allowance possible but that didn't help. Is there a way I could modify the filter so it isn't causing this issue, please? Many thanks in advance

```
import os

import numpy as np
import torch
from PIL import Image
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torchvision import transforms, utils
#from torchvision.transforms import Grayscalei
import pandas as pd
import pdb
import cv2

class CellsDataset(Dataset):
    # a very simple dataset

    def __init__(self, root_dir, transform=None, return_filenames=False):
        self.root = root_dir
        self.transform = transform
        self.return_filenames = return_filenames
        self.files = [os.path.join(self.root,filename) for filename in os.listdir(self.root)]
        self.files = [path for path in self.files
                      if os.path.isfile(path) and os.path.splitext(path)[1]=='.png']

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.files)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        path = self.files[idx]        
        image = cv2.imread(path)
        sample = image.copy()
        # set blue and green channels to 0
        sample[:, :, 0] = 0
        sample[:, :, 1] = 0

channel.
        if self.transform:
            sample = self.transform(sample)

        if self.return_filenames:
            return sample, path
        else:
            return sample
```

Comment: Can you iterate over the dataset itself (not the DataLoader) without issue? e.g. `for x in dataset:`. If so then perhaps you need to decrease your data-loader's `num_workers`?

Answer (score 4):

Similar problem I met before. 
One possible solution is to disable `cv2` multi-processing by

```py
def __getitem__(self, idx):
    import cv2
    cv2.setNumThreads(0)
    # ...
```

in your dataloader. It might be because the `cv2` multi-processing is conflict with `torch`'s `DataLoader` with multi-processing. Although it does not work for me since mine does not involve OpenCV. But indeed you might first try this.

For my occasion, it's worth mentioning that torch's [multiprocessing](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/multiprocessing.html) with CUDA access must use `spawn` or `forkserver` instead of `fork` to spawn new process. To do this, you should

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import multiprocessing
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
    # ... **The all rest code**
```

Notice you shall put all remaining code in the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block, including the imports, because it might be other imports (like `cv2`) setting it to `fork` and your loaders does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think, after so many days you must have found a solution. I had the same problem. In my case, Out Of Memory Killer killed the process. I don't know if my solution will work or I'm not sure it might be relevant, but I hope it will give some direction to those who are new to this same problem.

The problem can be solved in several ways. Increasing the amount of RAM in the system will eliminate the problem. Or it can be eliminated by increasing the swap memory of the system.

This is how to set swap memory in Linux.

```
linux@linux:~# fallocate -l 32G /tmp/swap
linux@linux:~# chmod 600 /tmp/swap
linux@linux:~# mkswap /tmp/swap
linux@linux:~# swapon /tmp/swap
```

*I have found the idea of increasing swap from [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/maskrcnn-benchmark/issues/195#issuecomment-588966103).*

Or the easiest way would be to reduce the batch size of training. Smaller batch size will cost less memory. Give a try by setting the batch size to half what it has.

Another option is to decrease dataloaders `num_workers`. This also reduces the uses of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used **L**ightning **M**emory-**M**apped **D**atabase (**[LMDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_Memory-Mapped_Database)**) and it fixed.

This [link](https://www.programmerall.com/article/98151933086/) is a good example of how to use it.

Comment: Please, describe the solution in detail and add references

Comment: It is very obvious. if you search lmdb, you will find lots of resources for doing that.
Why did you vote not useful while you didn't check the keyword that I provided.